# mysql - combining 2 tables with different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i have 2 tables user and userStore

```
user Table
╔════╦══════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║  ROLE  ║ STORECODE ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ A    ║ Admin  ║           ║
║  2 ║ B    ║ Store  ║         1 ║
║  3 ║ C    ║ Store  ║           ║
║  4 ║ D    ║ Client ║           ║
║  5 ║ E    ║ Staff  ║           ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╩═══════════╝

userStore Table
╔════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ CATEGORY ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ X        ║
║  2 ║ X        ║
╚════╩══════════╝

Output
╔════╦══════╦════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║  ROLE  ║ STORECODE ║ CATEGORY ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ A    ║ Admin  ║           ║          ║
║  2 ║ B    ║ Store  ║         1 ║ X        ║
║  4 ║ D    ║ Client ║           ║          ║
║  5 ║ E    ║ Staff  ║           ║          ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

I want to fetch all the rows from user table with the role other than store. And wanted to include the store role only if it have match in the userstore table.
In the output you can see that the id=3 is not available since it doesn't have match from user store.

Comment: My condition is if role=store then it has to have a row in userstore otherwise i dont want that row to be fetched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be straight forward, use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    user a
        LEFT JOIN userStore b
            ON a.StoreCode = b.ID
WHERE   (a.role <> 'Store') OR 
        (a.role = 'Store' AND NOT b.ID IS NULL )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1305/10)

Other Source

- [Visual Representation of Join](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.role, u.StoreCode, IFNULL(us.id, '') id, IFNULL(us.Category, '') Category
FROM USER u 
LEFT JOIN userStore us ON u.StoreCode = us.id 
WHERE IF(LOWER(u.role) = 'store', u.StoreCode IS NOT NULL AND u.StoreCode != '', TRUE);
```